# multilevel model_data type

Tags: multilevel-analysis, model

I would like to use multilevel model for analyzing 2-levels experience sampling data. Level 1 data are within person observations, collected on 3 days on 5 random occasions. Level 2 data are demographics and personality variables.

My problem is that my dependent variable is dichotomous (yes, no) and not continuous as prescribed by the multilevel model.

What can I do circumvent this fence?
Thank you for your help

Comment: You can do binomial logistic multilevel regression; multilevel doesn't need continuous dependent variables.